# Why is SubmitDiagInfo failing on Yosemite?

Tags: macos

My syslog shows the following:

```
Oct 16 05:47:47 Yosemite-Guertin.local SubmitDiagInfo[299]: Removed expired problem report: file:///Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/awdd_2015-09-15-191203_Yosemite-Guertin.awd
Oct 16 05:47:47 Yosemite-Guertin.local SubmitDiagInfo[299]: Submitted problem report file:///Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/awdd_2015-10-15-224315_Yosemite-Guertin.awd
Oct 16 05:47:48 Yosemite-Guertin.local SubmitDiagInfo[299]: Connection to https://radarsubmissions.apple.com/submit failed. statusCode: 500 error: (null)
Oct 16 05:47:48 Yosemite-Guertin.local SubmitDiagInfo[299]: Error while submitting usage and diagnostic messages. SubmitDiagInfo failed to submit diagnostic messages
```

Is this a concern?  If so, is there a cure?

Answer (score 1):

When your Mac generates diagnostic logs, submitting them to Apple helps them know what issues are actually happening as opposed to one person reporting a bug. In the long term, not sending any reports is bad for you since your issues will be underweighted / undervalued and other people's crashes will possibly get more attention.

In the short term, one or two errors likely won't make any difference.

To figure out the error, you could use the command line to open a test connection to the server indicated in the failure message:

```
openssl s_client -connect radarsubmissions.apple.com:443
```

Several lines of text should flow by if you have no errors or issues. The tail end of a successful test should look like:

```
SSL handshake has read 2962 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 9B9A3A1B0136419E428B0857BEBDE5CA2EC2276083B9A6568943E475B59D7F25
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 976B51D8E678BB520EEB66BB701510F40620551AFE88A51D62F0167434D9695A0784A4DDA8956CE1EBA73ED034BA8AC5
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1445003611
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

At this point, you wan wait for the timeout or press control-D one time to exit the openssl test connection. The obvious thing that would break is if your computer and Apple's servers thought the time *now* was more than 4 or 5 minutes apart. You can go to your system preferences and toggle the "set time automatically" switch once or twice to get your clock updated with Apple's public time servers.

Comment: This is what I got, which DID have errors:

Leopard-Guertin:~ dickguertin$ openssl s_client -connect radarsubmissions.apple.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=California/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=C0806592/C=US/.... more

Comment: I'm unable to give a longer answer using Comment. What other way can I show the entire dialog?

Comment: Certificate chain
 0 s:/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=California/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=C0806592/C=US/postalCode=95014/ST=California/L=Cupertino/street=1 Infinite Loop/O=Apple Inc./OU=GNCS Traffic Management/CN=radarsubmissions-new.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc.

Comment: @Dickster the  main thing is you have a start time, the timeout isn't zero in the return code is zero   - if you want to, ask the following question asking if your SSL handshake is valid and then you can post the same amount of information that I did

Comment: bmike: my original question is still valid. I'm new to Yosemite, and for "openssl" to also fail with "verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate" adds to my confusion. I don't understand your response.